# Nested For loop with async module in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm trying to execute a nested for loop with `async` module in order to handle the asynchronous of `nightmare` callbacks functions. So briefly, what I'm doing is that I'm running few `nightmare` objects in the same `node` instance to go over different links on a website.

According to what I have read, I must call `next()` function in order to notify the `asyncOfSeries`loop to move on to the next index. This is working fine with just one for loop. When I have nested `asyncOfSeries`, the inner `next()` function is not executing on the inner loop, just on the outer loop.

Please see the snippet of the code so you can understand better:

```
 var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
 var nightmare = Nightmare({show:true})

var complexObject = {

 19:["11","12","13","14","15"],
 21:["16"],
 22:["17"],
 23:["18","19"]
};
//looping on each object property
async.eachOfSeries(complexObject, function(item, keyDo, next){
  //here im looping on each key of the object, which are arrays
  async.eachOfSeries(item, function(indexs, key, nexts){
    nightmare
    .//do something
    .then(function(body){

        nightmare
        .//do something
        .then(function(body2){

           nightmare
          .//do something
          .then(function(body3){

            //Here I call next() and expecting to call the next index of the inner loop
            //but is calling the next index of the outer loop and the inner for is just 
           // executing one time.
             next();
          });

        });

    });
 }); 
});
```

I've tried  to call another `next()` after the inner loop but is throwing an error. Does anyone has an idea why the inner loop is running just one time ?

Comment: Where you declare a variable `nightmare`?

Comment: I have edited the snippet. @stdob--

Comment: Since you are using promises, you probably shouldn't use  async.js. They don't compose well (and you don't handle errors at all).

Comment: You've got a typo: `nexts` instead of `next`. You have to call the inner `next` in the inner callback, and you have to pass the outer `next` as the callback to `eachOfSeries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two callbacks you need to manage.  The inner callback "nexts" and the outer callback "next".  You are calling the outer callback from within your inner loop.

Try this:

```
    var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
 var nightmare = Nightmare({show:true})

var complexObject = {

 19:["11","12","13","14","15"],
 21:["16"],
 22:["17"],
 23:["18","19"]
};
//looping on each object property
async.eachOfSeries(complexObject, function(item, keyDo, next){
  //here im looping on each key of the object, which are arrays
  async.eachOfSeries(item, function(indexs, key, nexts){
    nightmare
    .//do something
    .then(function(body){

        nightmare
        .//do something
        .then(function(body2){

           nightmare
          .//do something
          .then(function(body3){

            //Here I call next() and expecting to call the next index of the inner loop
            //but is calling the next index of the outer loop and the inner for is just 
           // executing one time.
             nexts();
          });

        });

    });
 }); 
next();
});
```

Comment: Definitely legit, I actually had a typo pasting the code here, but in my code I have both callbacks with the same name next(). I guess since they are on the same scope that was causing issue, I'll try this. thanks!